# How can I INNER JOIN another two columns to a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM newsTable INNER JOIN picTable on picTable.picID = newsTable.newsPicID
```

This links the selected image from one table to a news story in another table.

This only works for one image, but if I was to have up to 3 images that could be added for one story, what would my new SQL statement look like?

I can't quite get my head round the syntax of the **new** SQL statement.

Any guidance much appreciated.

```
newsTable

newsID
newsTitle
newsBody
newsPicID
newsPicIDTwo
newsPicIDThree

picTable

picID
picFileName
picPath
```

Comment: Bad table design. You need another table to link news to pictures.

Comment: agreed, just create another table to link newsTable and picTable, much easier, and query will be simple too

Comment: @jarlh That is slightly subjective, if there has to be 3 pictures for every record, then I would say it is good design, or if there is a maximum of 3 pictures, it might not be fully normalised, but that isn't always a bad thing. In the same way that having `AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3` in a table is not bad design, I would not advocate a separate `AddressLine` table. It might be that a separate table is the best solution here, but I couldn't say for sure just on the information provided.

Comment: @GarethD, and then someone suddenly wants a 4th picture to an article. I wouldn't recommend `alter table add column pic4` then... (An address format is more or less the same, new levels aren't added very often.)

Comment: You are making assumptions. If it is known that there will only ever be 3 images, then there is no problem with this, and it makes the query to get all 3 in the same row simpler, it makes limiting the number of pictures to 3 much simpler. The cost of this simplicity is a lack of flexibility, but if it is known that this will never, or seldom change then it is not a bad design. I am not saying you are wrong, my point is that you can't simply make a blanket statement of "Bad Design" based on information available.

Comment: @Gareth Sorry for interrupting, but I think that jarlh is correct. A good DB design is not subjective. OP describes a classic 1 to Many relationship. The way you have to design the tables is known in such a case, and the design he followed is wrong.

Comment: @apomene I am not saying he is wrong. I am saying it is impossible to tell if he is right. Let's consider a Facebook profile page type scenario with a Cover photo and a profile picture. In this scenario, I would have two columns in a Profile Table, CoverPictureID and ProfilePictureID. What you are saying is that this is wrong, and should be stored in a separate table. Subjective was perhaps not the right word, but whether or not it should be stored in 3 columns, or 3 rows in a separate table is not black and white and depends on information we do not have.

Comment: @vimsliu would you mind showing me how I can do it with anoter table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join two more times to bring in the picture information:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       COALESCE(t2.picFileName, 'NA') AS picFileName1,
       COALESCE(t3.picFileName, 'NA') AS picFileName2,
       COALESCE(t4.picFileName, 'NA') AS picFileName3
FROM newsTable t1
LEFT JOIN picTable t2
    ON t1.newsPicID      = t2.picID
LEFT JOIN picTable t3
    ON t1.newsPicIDTwo   = t3.picID
LEFT JOIN picTable t4
    ON t1.newsPicIDThree = t4.picID
```

You can add more columns here from the `picTable` as you need, and possibly use `COALESCE()` again to provide a default value should a news item not have any picture information.

Comment: Forgive me for being a bit thick Tim, but what are t1, t2, t3 etc? And can the default value be anything?

Comment: These are called table _aliases_.  Once you alias a table using e.g. `t1`, you can refer to that table in the rest of the query as `t1`.  They were introduced to make a query easier to read, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this:

```
SELECT newsTable.*, pic.*, picTwo.*, picThree.*
FROM newsTable
INNER JOIN picTable AS pic on picTable.picID = newsTable.newsPicID 
INNER JOIN picTable AS picTwo on picTable.picID = newsTable.newsPicIDTwo
INNER JOIN picTable AS picThree on picTable.picID = newsTable.newsPicIDThree
```

if newsPicIDTwo or newsPicIDThree are NULL you schould use an LEFT OUTER JOIN

Answer (score 1):

Just `left join` the `picTable` three times:

```
select *
from newsTable t
left join picTable p1 on p1.picID = t.newsPicID
left join picTable p2 on p2.picID = t.newsPicIDTwo
left join picTable p3 on p3.picID = t.newsPicIDThree
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Use LEFT OUTER JOIN to get three pictures :

SELECT * FROM newsTable 
LEFT OUTER JOIN picTable PIC1 on PIC1.picID = newsTable.newsPicID
LEFT OUTER JOIN picTable PIC2 on PIC2.picID = newsTable.newsPicIDTwo
LEFT OUTER JOIN picTable PIC3 on PIC3.picID = newsTable.newsPicIDThree
```

Answer (score 1):

As you describe your problem, you have 1 to many relationship from news to images. That means that each news id can have multiple picds.
 Show  you don't need `newsPicIDTwo` and  `newsPicIDThree` fields on `newsTable` and you need a field `newsid` on table `picTable`. Simply, then

```
SELECT * FROM newsTable INNER JOIN picTable on picTable.newsID = newsTable.newsID
```

Will bring you the correct result if you have records on `picTable` that have same `newsID` but different `picID`

In other words, a classic 1-Many relationship is resolved correctly when the foreign key lies on the 'Many' table.

In your case the 'Many' table is `picTable` that owes to have a foreign key `newsid`.

Answer (score 0):

Just join again on the appropraite columns. I've used Left joins in case one of the pic columns is empty

```
SELECT NT.*, p1.picFileName as P1File, p2.picFileName as P2File, p3.picFileName as P3File
FROM newsTable NT
LEFT JOIN picTable P1 
  on P1.picID = NT.newsPicID
LEFT JOIN picTable P2 
  on P2.picID = NT.newsPicIDtwo
LEFT JOIN picTable P3
  on P3.picID = NT.newsPicIDthree
```